# Disable buttons when one of them selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

I got a series of button and I wanna select one, but when that happens the other buttons disable.

I'm trying to do it, but it's not working. It selects but after that disables every button i have. Please help.

https://jsfiddle.net/KukApep3/cq45d3fq/#&togetherjs=Qg4mmTfbne

```js
    var supermercado;
    
    $("button").click(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass("selected");
      $("button").each(function(){
        if($(this).is(":selected")){
          supermercado = $(this).text();
        } else {
          $(this).prop("disabled", true);
        };
       });
     });
```

```css
    button {
      border:none;
      display:inline-block;
      outline:0;
      padding:8px 16px;
      color:#fff;
      background-color:#009688;
      text-align:center;
      cursor:pointer;
      white-space:nowrap;
      margin: 20px;
     }
     
     button:hover, .selected {
       color:#000;
       background-color:#bbb;
     }
     
    .selected {
       border: 2px solid black;
     }
     
     .inline-list {display: inline-flex;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inline-list">
      <button>Jumbo</button>
      <button>Continente</button>
      <button>Lidl</button>
      <button>Pingo Doce</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: ":selected" is not class

Comment: What happens if they select the wrong thing? Are they out of luck?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Well if they are disabled, how can you select a different one?

Comment: that's what i wanted to know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your code currently loops through all the buttons when any of them is clicked and then checks to see if each one is `selected` (rather that has the `selected` class applied to it), which will never happen with a button, so each one becomes disabled. And, once they are disabled, they can't be clicked to re-enable them.

Rather than disabling the buttons, I think you just want to remove the `.selected` class.

You don't need the loop at all because you can just  remove the `.selected` class from all the buttons, apply it to just the button that was clicked and get the text of the button that was clicked - that is the selected button. Remove that loop and it works.

```js
var supermercado;
    
$("button").click(function(){
  // Remove the selected class from all buttons
  $("button").removeClass("selected");

  // Apply the selected class to just the clicked button
  $(this).toggleClass("selected");

  // Set the text to the text of the button that was just clicked
  supermercado = $(this).text();
});
```

```css
button {
      border:none;
      display:inline-block;
      outline:0;
      padding:8px 16px;
      color:#fff;
      background-color:#009688;
      text-align:center;
      cursor:pointer;
      white-space:nowrap;
      margin: 20px;
     }
     
     button:hover, .selected {
       color:#000;
       background-color:#bbb;
     }
     
    .selected {
       border: 2px solid black;
     }
     
     .inline-list {display: inline-flex;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inline-list">
      <button>Jumbo</button>
      <button>Continente</button>
      <button>Lidl</button>
      <button>Pingo Doce</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what i wanted, simple and clean, perfect , thank you :)

Comment: I can't up vote at the moment, 'cause i'm new here, but i market as the answer, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try using has class rather than the `.is(":selected")` as that attributed doesn't apply to buttons

```js
 var supermercado;

  $("button").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    if($(this).hasClass("selected")){
      $("button").each(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("selected")){
          supermercado = $(this).text();
        } else {
          $(this).prop("disabled", true);
        };
      });
     } else {
       $("button").prop("disabled", false);
     }
   });
```

```css
    button {
      border:none;
      display:inline-block;
      outline:0;
      padding:8px 16px;
      color:#fff;
      background-color:#009688;
      text-align:center;
      cursor:pointer;
      white-space:nowrap;
      margin: 20px;
     }
     
     button:hover, .selected {
       color:#000;
       background-color:#bbb;
     }
     
    .selected {
       border: 2px solid black;
     }
     
     .inline-list {display: inline-flex;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inline-list">
      <button>Jumbo</button>
      <button>Continente</button>
      <button>Lidl</button>
      <button>Pingo Doce</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Uner what condition do you want to undisable them?

Comment: they disable when the selected button "unselects"

Comment: ok cool, now you will need to choose the accepted answer as my answer is much different to the current accepted answer.